# Why scrollbar are empty?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to add second scroll-bar to top of table. But problem that it's not it do not scrollable.

http://jsfiddle.net/tpersu4d/

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="wrapper1">
    <div class="div1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper2">
    <div class="div2">
      <el-table :data=tableData>
         <el-table-column prop="name" prop="name" ></el-table-column>
         <el-table-column prop="address" ></el-table-column>
      </el-table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scroll, because your content fits in the screen width, but even if you make your div longer, it would just grow. To make it scrollable, you need to put it in a fixed width container.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper1">
       <div class="div1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper2">
       <div class="div2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

.container {
  width: 100vw;
}

.div2 { 
  width: 150%;
}
```

[Here is the updated version.](https://jsfiddle.net/29n4dt3v/2/)